# How can i declare list with values in single line in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

How can i declare a list in single line? 
In groovy i can do something like below

```
def l = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

What is the kotlin equivalent for this?

Comment: Tried that "prior research" thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily find it in Kotlin [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html):

```
val list = listOf('a', 'b', 'c')
```

---

```
/** Returns a new read-only list of given elements.  
 *  The returned list is serializable (JVM).
 */
public fun <T> listOf(vararg elements: T): List<T> 
        = if (elements.size > 0) elements.asList() else emptyList()
```